# Relative Extrema and Taylor's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, derivatives, continuity

I was watching [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HO2TNOsrg6c&ab_channel=COSMOSLEARNING) and in the proof, he applies Taylor's theorem for the interval $V_\delta(x_0)$, since $f$ and its derivatives $f', f'', \dots, f^{(n)}$ exist and are continuous in $V_\delta(x_0)$.

But what I don't understand is how Taylor's theorem would apply if $V_\delta(x_0)$ is an open interval. According to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOOIG84dR4g&list=PLrvK1zCpb85AtQZjin-IJLRK4uOMX0Hji&index=52&ab_channel=AndrewMcCrady), Taylor's theorem applies if the interval $I=[a, b]$ is closed.

Can someone please explain? Thank you.

Comment: Taylor's theorem allows one to describe the behavior of a function near a point at which enough derivatives are known. There are many slightly different versions of the statement. Do some research about that. About linking videos, you'll have a better chance of getting an answer if you at least transcribe the relevant parts somewhere in your question.